# How to register own CQL filter in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, filter, opengis

I have created new [FilterFactory](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/opengis/filter/class-use/FilterFactory.html) implementation, added it to META-INF/services in file org.opengis.filter.FilterFactory. 
Added Interface extending Filter. 
Added implementation of this Interface. 
When I try to call it in cql_filter I get CQLException "Function not found"..
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add the jar to geoserver?

Comment: Yes, of course. I see the factory, I created was successfully created, but when I call my filter in cql_filter query, I receive Exception - Function not found.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Please look in the log files and add any relevant error messages to your question using the [edit] button